# Pointer to derivate class member function from pointer to base class member function

Tags: c++, base-class, pointer-to-member

What are the C++ rules to make this program to compile?

```
struct A
{ void f() {}; };

struct B : A
{};

int main()
{
    void (B::*ptr)() = &A::f;
    (void)ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that `A::f` is a member of class `B`, but what are the specific rules that allow this assignment? I'm a bit confused for this. Does the compiler check that the address of `A::f` is a member of `B` or what?

Comment: Every member of `A` is also a member of `B`. I'm not sure what you find unclear about this code.

Comment: Because once the address is taken, you don't know what specific function are you considering. An example to break encapsulation from this assignment: if you make `f` private in `B` (`private: using A::f`), you can call `f` from an instance of `b` using the pointer. I was confused because of this open door.

Comment: You can also call that function via `b.A::f()` or `((A&)b).f()`. Using pointer-to-member doesn't add any capabilities that weren't already available otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah makes sense indeed. `A::f` is public after all, you only have to move to the base subobject first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verse from the standard that makes the initialization of `ptr` well-formed would be

> [**[conv.mem]/2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.mem#2) A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B` of type `cv T`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type `cv T`”, where `D` is a complete class derived (**[class.derived]**) from `B`...

Hope this helps.